# Assign a hidden name to a GitHub anchor for easier linking?

Tags: github, anchor, github-flavored-markdown

In my repo's wiki, I have a header that is an actual function prototype:

```
### void SomeFunction(string param1, int param2)
```

Is it possible to assign a special name to this so I can link to it easier? Something like [MultiMarkdown's labels](http://fletcher.github.io/peg-multimarkdown/index#cross-references). For example:

```
### [void SomeFunction(string param1, int param2) | SomeFunctionAnchor]
### void SomeFunction(string param1, int param2) [SomeFunctionAnchor]
[Click this.](#SomeFunctionAnchor)
```

If not, is there a way to do this in any of GitHub's other markdown methods (i.e., AsciiDoc, Creole, MediaWiki, Org-mode, Pod, RDoc, Textile, ReStructuredText)?

Answer (score 2):

like this.

```
### <a name="SomeFunctionAnchor">void SomeFunction(string param1, int param2)
[Click this.](#SomeFunctionAnchor)
```